# R: Profvis doesn't show any results

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to fix my code to be faster. I've reading and I've been introduced to `profvis` package.

The thing is that it works in excercise but not with my real code.

This is the excersice code I'm talking about:

```
library("profvis")
profvis({
  data(movies, package = "ggplot2movies") # Load data
  movies = movies[movies$Comedy == 1,]
  plot(movies$year, movies$rating)
  model = loess(rating ~ year, data = movies) # loess regression line
  j = order(movies$year)
  lines(movies$year[j], model$fitted[j]) # Add line to the plot
})
```

And this is my code (the one I need to optimize):
But `profvis` only shows a blank screen.

```
library("profvis")
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(urltools)




#start RSelenium


rD  <- rsDriver(port = 4506L, browser = "firefox", version = "latest", chromever = "latest",
                geckover = "latest", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
                verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE)



remDr <- rD[["client"]]




### URLS ###



falabella_urls <- c("http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=0&Nrpp=1000",
                    "http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=1000&Nrpp=1000")


#############################


testaaa <- function() {


falabella_data_list <- list()




for (i in falabella_urls$url[1:2]) {

  remDr$navigate(i)

  print(i)

  Sys.sleep(05)

  page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()




  product_info <- function(node){


    subcategoria_url <- str_split(path(i), "\\/")[[1]][4]
    s.marca <- html_nodes(node,"div.marca a") %>% html_text
    s.producto <- html_nodes(node,"div.detalle a") %>% html_attr("href")
    s.precio.antes <- html_nodes(node, "div.precio2 span") %>% html_text
    s.precio.actual <- html_nodes(node, "div.precio1 span") %>% html_text 

    data.frame(
      fecha = as.character(Sys.Date()),
      subcategoria = subcategoria_url,
      ecommerce = "Falabella",
      marca = s.marca,
      producto = s.producto,
      precio.antes = ifelse(length(s.precio.antes) == 0, NA, s.precio.antes),
      precio.actual = ifelse(length(s.precio.actual) == 0, NA, s.precio.actual),
      stringsAsFactors=F
    )


  }



  doc <- read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]]), to="UTF-8") %>% 
    html_nodes(".cajaLP4x")




  productos <- lapply(doc, product_info) %>%
    bind_rows()


  falabella_data_list[[i]] <- productos # add it to your list




}





falabella = do.call(rbind, falabella_data_list)

}


profvis({testaaa()})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you can try to put all of your code in profvis({...})

```
profvis({
library("profvis")
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(urltools)




#start RSelenium


rD  <- rsDriver(port = 4506L, browser = "firefox", version = "latest", chromever = "latest",
                geckover = "latest", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
                verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE)



remDr <- rD[["client"]]




### URLS ###



falabella_urls <- c("http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=0&Nrpp=1000",
                    "http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=1000&Nrpp=1000")


#############################


testaaa <- function() {


falabella_data_list <- list()




for (i in falabella_urls$url[1:2]) {

  remDr$navigate(i)

  print(i)

  Sys.sleep(05)

  page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()




  product_info <- function(node){


    subcategoria_url <- str_split(path(i), "\\/")[[1]][4]
    s.marca <- html_nodes(node,"div.marca a") %>% html_text
    s.producto <- html_nodes(node,"div.detalle a") %>% html_attr("href")
    s.precio.antes <- html_nodes(node, "div.precio2 span") %>% html_text
    s.precio.actual <- html_nodes(node, "div.precio1 span") %>% html_text 

    data.frame(
      fecha = as.character(Sys.Date()),
      subcategoria = subcategoria_url,
      ecommerce = "Falabella",
      marca = s.marca,
      producto = s.producto,
      precio.antes = ifelse(length(s.precio.antes) == 0, NA, s.precio.antes),
      precio.actual = ifelse(length(s.precio.actual) == 0, NA, s.precio.actual),
      stringsAsFactors=F
    )


  }



  doc <- read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]]), to="UTF-8") %>% 
    html_nodes(".cajaLP4x")




  productos <- lapply(doc, product_info) %>%
    bind_rows()


  falabella_data_list[[i]] <- productos # add it to your list




}





falabella = do.call(rbind, falabella_data_list)

}


})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, 
and I find a way that you can try.
fistly:run this example in your Rstudio,

```
p <- profvis({
pause(0.5)}) 
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, "title")
```

and,you will meet the question:
*Error in system(paste(shQuote(pandoc_path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) : 
  '"C:/Users/admin/Anaconda3/Library/bin/pandoc"' not found*

so you need to install the [pandoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGoGV.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGoGV.png): https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.1.3,just in your route way by the error information.

and you try your code by profvis({}), it may solve your problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGoGV.png)

Comment: `p <- profvis({   
  data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")   
  plot(price ~ carat, data = diamonds)   
  m <- lm(price ~ carat, data = diamonds)   
  abline(m, col = "red")   
})`   run this code,  after get the picture,  type  `p` in your console , the    profile file will take place